# Mysql сортировка по родителю

Tags: mysql, сортировка, order, parent

Столкнулся с проблемой сортировки по родителю. Может у кого есть опыт решения этой проблемы?

```
SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY ...
```

Нужно чтобы дочерний элемент шел рекурсивно сразу после родителя. К примеру так

| id | parent_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Первый в списке |
| 2 | 1 | Родитель 1 |
| 5 | 0 | Без родителя |
| 3 | 5 | Родитель 5 |
| 4 | 3 | Родитель 3 |

Итог

```
1
..2
5
..3
....4
```

Пробовал так, но рекурсивно не получается:

```
SELECT * FROM comments
ORDER BY 
   CASE
       WHEN parent_id = 0  
       THEN id
       ELSE parent_id 
   END DESC
```

Буду рад любому решению, чем проще тем лучше

Comment: То что вы называете рекурсией не является рекурсия

Comment: А что значит "не получается"? Ошибка выходит или сортировка не та?

Comment: Укажите точную версию MySQL. В общем - строите FQpath и по нему сортируете.

Comment: Сортировка не та по итогу. 
Простыми словами получается  что  1->2  и 5->3 идут как надо, а 4 элемент не  следует за его родителем, в данном случае 3.
Нужно добиться варианта 1->2    5->3->4

Comment: Версия MYSQL 8.0.24

Comment: Akina, Спасибо за решение.
https://qna.habr.com/q/1299048